# Why does runZonedGuarded prevent following code from executing?

Tags: dart, asynchronous

Observe the following code.

```
void main() async {
  await runZonedGuarded(
    () async {
      print("a");
      throw "error";
    },
    (e, s) {
      print("b");
    },
  );
  print("c");
}
```

It only prints...

```
a
b
```

Instead of ...

```
a
b
c
```

If I remove the throw it prints

```
a
c
```

Can someone explain what exactly is going on here? Why does c not print in the first case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dart has the notion of ["error zones"](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Zone/errorZone.html). When you introduce an error handler in  a zone, any error future belonging to that zone will refuse to propagate its error to a future belonging to a different error zone.

The `runZonedGuarded` function installs an error handler to handle asynchronous errors, but that also means that the future you return, a `Future<void>`, belongs to that zone. You don't throw an error inside the `runZonedGuarded`, instead you return a future containing an error.
The `onError` handler isn't triggered on the return.

When you then try to `await` the future, after having left the function, the error zone gets in the way. Instead of re-throwing the error at the `await`, it instead makes the error an uncaught error in the error zone (which is why it prints `b`), and then the future *doesn't complete at all* at the `await`.
That's highly confusing.

See also: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/39825

As a recommendation: Don't return futures from `runZonedGuarded`. That's ... not very usable, because the reason to use zones at all is to do asynchronous computations.